# sencha extjs 5.0 app not working in production build

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have just built a new app with ExtJS 5.0 which seems to be really awesome.

The app is working fine in development mode, but as soon as I build the app with the command line tools and deploy it, it stops working.

The build command I use when I'm in the directory of the project:

```
sencha app build production
```

The command works fine so far, no error is in the output.
I'm using a little server-side with php, so I have to change the ending of the index.html to index.php and also include the php folder again manually in the production server. (I didn't find out how to change that in the build process itself)

so far, everything seems fine for me in the basic output of my index file, but the app won't start because of an error in the console:

```
GET http://admin.vp24.com/.js?_dc=1404608946314 404 (Not Found) (index):23
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

What does Ext try to include here?

When I start the app in development mode i see many includes of basic class files and stuff in the network tab which works - here it only starts with an include of an empty file called `.js` which seems totally broken.

I tried to debug the part `fetchSync` of the `app.js` file (the basic Ext stuff i think) to find out which thing I he tries to include at that point and it seems to me that it is the `gridfilters-plugin`.

Some variables are suddenly `null` during all that steps there and I don't know why.

What can be wrong with the app?

Comment: Did you try `sencha app build production`?

Comment: Try `sencha app build testing` and see if you get any runtime errors. Don't forget to "pause on exceptions" in your devtools, so you can walk the stack trace and find the culprit.

Comment: i totally forgot to answer, thanks to @arthurakay, this gave me the solution.. i was missing an import for grid-filters. answer that again as a full answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sencha app build testing` and see if you get any runtime errors.

Don't forget to "pause on exceptions" in your devtools, so you can walk the stack trace and find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing **validations** from your models.